# How can I disable a selected date on the Material UI calendar once the value is submited (booking system)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, calendar, datetimepicker

I integrated a simple calendar using Material UI Date & Time picker, which I would like to use inside my react app form to allow users to select a date and time (like a booking system) and submit it with their name and email. My idea was that once the user booked a date/time in the calendar. I Will be saved in an array. Then I'll check if the user selects the same date/time then I'll disable it in the calendar, so it will not be booked again. I tried to use ShouldDisableDate and I've done a lot of research, but I got stuck...

This is the documentation https://material-ui-pickers.dev/demo/datetime-picker

Ps: The booking component is separated from the form component. And the click button is only for debugging

What do you think?

```
import React, {useState } from "react";

import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { DateTimePicker, MuiPickersUtilsProvider} from "@material-ui/pickers";

function Booking() {

  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState(new Date());
  const [calendarData, setCalendardata] = useState([]);
  console.log(calendarData);
  console.log(selectedDate);

  let stringfySelectedDate = JSON.stringify(selectedDate);

  const onSubmitDate = (e) => {
    e.preventdefault();
    
    // If the the array length is === to zero then add the first element
    if(calendarData.length === 0) {
      setCalendardata([...calendarData, stringfySelectedDate]);
      console.log("empty array");
    }

    if(calendarData.includes(stringfySelectedDate)) {
      console.log("already exist");
      return calendarData;
    } else {
      setCalendardata([...calendarData, JSON.stringify(selectedDate)]);
    }
  
  }

  
  return (
    <>
    <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
      <DateTimePicker
        label="Book"
        inputVariant="outlined"
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={handleDateChange}
        shouldDisableDate={}
        disablePast
        showTodayButton
        clearable
        id="calendar"
      />
    </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
    <div className="col-12">
                          <div className="text-center">
                            <button
                              onClick={onSubmitDate}
                              className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
                            >
                              <span className="ls3 text-u">click</span>
                            </button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default Booking;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `shouldDisableDate` props. `shouldDisableDate` type is  `(date) => boolean`.

```
const [calendarData, setCalendardata] = useState([]);

const onSubmitDate = (e) => {
   ///other actions
   setCalendardata([...calendarData, selectedDate.toDateString()]);
}
const checkDisableDate = (date) => {
   return calendarData.includes(date.toDateString());
};
return(
   <>
     //....
      <DateTimePicker
        ...otherProps
        shouldDisableDate={checkDisableDate}
      />
  </>
)
```

Update:
Above Solution is only date. if for time, should use dropdown.

```
const [selectedTime, setSelectedTime] = useState("0:00")

const onSubmitDate = (e) => {
   ///other actions
    const date = selectedDate.toLocaleDateString();
    const dateTime = date + "*TZ" + selectedTime;
    setCalendardata([...calendarData, dateTime ]);
    setSelectedTime("");
}
const checkDisableDateTime = (time) => {
    var arr = calendarData.filter(x => x.split("*TZ")[0] === 
                                   selectedDate.toLocaleDateString());
    return arr.some(x => x.split("*TZ")[1] === time);
} 
return (
   <>
   //Other components    
        <Select
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(e) => setSelectedTime(e.target.value || "")}
          label="Time"             
        >
          <MenuItem value="">
          Select
          </MenuItem>
          {
            times.map((item,index) => {
              return <MenuItem 
                       key={index} 
                       disabled={checkDisableDateTime(item)}  
                       value={item}>
              {item}
            </MenuItem>
            })
          }
      </Select>
  </>

)
```

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but I wasn't particularly looking to disable the calendar, but I would like to disable a date selected by a user once it is submitted, it's like a booking system once the user book a specific time he can't rebook it again...

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect! Would it be possible to disable a day until the time slots on that specific date are all booked( e.g., dentist booking system) ?

Comment: It's possible but cannot disable for time picker, so can select twice at same time. In Mui v4 has not shouldDisable props for timepicker. Optimal solution to use DatePicker and Time Dropdown.

Comment: I have edited solution using time dropdown.